# TCP write error but not really

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming

I have been testing a program which has simple communication between two machines over a 1Gbps line. While running TCP communications over the line I occasionally receive write errors on the client side (due to a timeout) when the network is totally flooded (running at or close to 100% usage). This generally happens when I am running multiple instances of the same program going to different ports.

My question is, is it possible to get a write error but still receive the message on the server side. It appears that is what is happening, and I am not quite sure why. Could it be that the ACK coming back to the client is what is timing out?

Comment: You receive what error?

Comment: A write error that is caught due to a timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. TCP does not guarantee you that data you sent successfully is received and that data that is sent unsuccessfully is not received. This problem is unsolvable. It is called the Generals Problem. There is always a way to loose messages/packets such that the sender comes to the wrong conclusion. TCP guarantees that the receiver receives the same stream of bytes that the sender sent, but possibly cut off at an arbitrary point.

This unreliability has performance reasons, too. TCP data is buffered on both hosts as well as on the network. Acknowledgement is delayed.

You have to live with this. If you make your scenario more concrete I can suggest some strategies of dealing with this.

Comment: Thank you, leading me to the generals problem was more or less what I was looking for

Comment: This is stated too broadly. TCP does guarantee that you won't receive data twice, or out of order, or with holes in it.

Answer (score 0):

`send` puts data into the TCP send buffer.

If the send buffer has no enough space, `send` will block util the data is completely or partly copied into the send buffer, or the designed timeout arrives.

Read timeout and write timeout is OK. You should check and process them. The way is restarting read/write operation after timeout. You also pay attention to other read/write error except timeout.